# Power of combined hypotheses test of two separate hypotheses

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

In a manuscript that I've read, the primary objective is to detect the effect of a treatment. To be able to generalize the statement, two different species (mice and rats) are included in the study. It is stated that the primary objective will be reached only if for both species the p-value of the main effect is below $0.05$, a "combined hypothesis test" so to say. A power analysis reveals that to detect a meaningful effect in mice with $80\%$ power, the sample size should be $N=20$. Since the same effect is assumed for rats, this sample size is used for mice as well as for rats.

In the manuscript it is claimed that this study has $80\%$ power to detect the effect. I do not think this is the case, since the probability to detect the effect in *both species* is $0.8 * 0.8 = 0.64$. A solution could be to plan with power of $\sqrt{0.8}$ for both species.

However, I was wondering which type I error rate for the individual species one should then choose to achieve a type I error rate of $0.05$ for the primary objective? How do I even define the effect sizes for mice and rats under the null hypothesis? Might this be an opportunity to apply Fisher's combination test?